# Embedding Processing applications in PowerPoint / Other Solutions

Tags: applet, powerpoint, processing

I wish to use the application known as Processing to create interactive graphs and figures to use in a presentation for the Arizona JSHS competition. I have used the widely popular LiveWeb application to be able to embed java into the power-point. But when I do the same thing with Java applications made with Processing it gives an error. 
"Error: Unexpected identifier or string. http://localhost/applet/index.html" 
I have tested it with locally hosted Java applets and Processing applets, both work run normally. But only the Java applet (which is very similar to the processing applet) works in LiveWeb. 
Does anyone have suggestions to get around this? Do you think I could import processing library's into Eclipse and work from there?

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution would be processing.js. It is a javascript version of processing that may fit your needs.